# pipi install is unable to install wxPython, failed with error code 1

Tags: wxpython

I'm trying to install wxPython because it is required to run a graphical python script debugger called winpdb. However, I've encountered an error. See the details below:

```
zhiwei@zhiwei-Lenovo-Rescuer-15ISK:~$ sudo proxychains pip install --upgrade --pre -f https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/snapshot-builds/ wxPython 
[sudo] password for zhiwei: 
ProxyChains-3.1 (http://proxychains.sf.net)
|DNS-request| ::1 
|S-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:1080-<><>-4.2.2.2:53-<><>-OK
|DNS-response|: ::1 does not exist
|DNS-request| ::1 
|S-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:1080-<><>-4.2.2.2:53-<><>-OK
|DNS-response|: ::1 does not exist
|DNS-request| ::1 
|S-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:1080-<><>-4.2.2.2:53-<><>-OK
|DNS-response|: ::1 does not exist
The directory '/home/zhiwei/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/zhiwei/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting wxPython
|DNS-request| pypi.python.org 
|S-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:1080-<><>-4.2.2.2:53-<><>-OK
|DNS-response| pypi.python.org is 151.101.52.223
|S-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:1080-<><>-151.101.52.223:443-<><>-OK
|DNS-request| wxpython.org 
|S-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:1080-<><>-4.2.2.2:53-<><>-OK
|DNS-response| wxpython.org is 173.212.231.191
|S-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:1080-<><>-173.212.231.191:443-<><>-OK
  Downloading https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/snapshot-builds/wxPython-4.0.0b2.dev3306+c1010c5.tar.gz (67.8MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 67.8MB 16kB/s 
|DNS-request| pypi.python.org 
|S-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:1080-<><>-4.2.2.2:53-<><>-OK
|DNS-response| pypi.python.org is 151.101.52.223
|S-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:1080-<><>-151.101.52.223:443-<><>-OK
|DNS-request| wxpython.org 
|S-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:1080-<><>-4.2.2.2:53-<><>-OK
|DNS-response| wxpython.org is 173.212.231.191
|S-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:1080-<><>-173.212.231.191:443-<><>-OK
Requirement already up-to-date: six in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from wxPython)
Installing collected packages: wxPython
  Running setup.py install for wxPython ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-AgBlvu/wxPython/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-q84GOx-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    WARNING: Building this way assumes that all generated files have been
    generated already.  If that is not the case then use build.py directly
    to generate the source and perform the build stage.  You can use
    --skip-build with the bdist_* or install commands to avoid this
    message and the wxWidgets and Phoenix build steps in the future.

    "/usr/bin/python" -u build.py build
    Will build using: "/usr/bin/python"
    2.7.13 (default, Jan 19 2017, 14:48:08)
    [GCC 6.3.0 20170118]
    Python's architecture is 64bit
    cfg.VERSION: 4.0.0b2.dev3306+c1010c5

    Running command: build
    Running command: build_wx
    wxWidgets build options: ['--wxpython', '--unicode', '--gtk3']
    Configure options: ['--enable-unicode', '--with-gtk=3', '--with-opengl', '--enable-sound', '--enable-graphics_ctx', '--enable-mediactrl', '--enable-display', '--enable-geometry', '--enable-debug_flag', '--enable-optimise', '--disable-debugreport', '--enable-uiactionsim', '--with-sdl']
    /tmp/pip-build-AgBlvu/wxPython/ext/wxWidgets/configure --enable-unicode --with-gtk=3 --with-opengl --enable-sound --enable-graphics_ctx --enable-mediactrl --enable-display --enable-geometry --enable-debug_flag --enable-optimise --disable-debugreport --enable-uiactionsim --with-sdl
    checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
    checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
    checking for --disable-gui... no
    checking for --enable-monolithic... no
    checking for --enable-plugins... no
    checking for --without-subdirs... no
    checking for --enable-official_build... no
    checking for --disable-all-features... no
    checking for --enable-universal... no
    checking for --enable-nanox... no
    checking for --enable-gpe... no
    checking for toolkit... gtk
    checking for --with-libpng... yes
    checking for --with-libjpeg... yes
    checking for --with-libtiff... yes
    checking for --without-libjbig... no
    checking for --without-liblzma... no
    checking for --with-libxpm... yes
    checking for --with-libiconv... yes
    checking for --with-libmspack... no
    checking for --without-gtkprint... no
    checking for --with-gnomevfs... no
    checking for --with-libnotify... yes
    checking for --with-hildon... no
    checking for --with-opengl... yes
    checking for --with-dmalloc... no
    checking for --with-sdl... yes
    checking for --with-regex... yes
    checking for --with-zlib... yes
    checking for --with-expat... yes
    checking for --with-macosx-sdk...
    checking for --with-macosx-version-min...
    checking for --enable-debug... default
    checking for --disable-debug_flag... no
    checking for --enable-debug_info... no
    checking for --enable-debug_gdb... no
    checking for --enable-debug_cntxt... no
    checking for --enable-mem_tracing... no
    checking for --disable-shared... no
    checking for --enable-stl... no
    checking for --enable-std_containers... no
    checking for --enable-std_iostreams... yes
    checking for --enable-std_string... yes
    checking for --enable-std_string_conv_in_wxstring... no
    checking for --disable-unicode... no
    checking for --enable-mslu... no
    checking for --enable-utf8... no
    checking for --enable-utf8only... no
    checking for --enable-extended_rtti... no
    checking for --disable-optimise... no
    checking for --enable-profile... no
    checking for --enable-no_rtti... no
    checking for --enable-no_exceptions... no
    checking for --enable-permissive... no
    checking for --enable-no_deps... no
    checking for --disable-vararg_macros... no
    checking for --enable-universal_binary... no
    checking for --enable-macosx_arch... no
    checking for --enable-compat26... no
    checking for --disable-compat28... no
    checking for --disable-rpath... no
    checking for --enable-objc_uniquifying... no
    checking for --disable-visibility... no
    checking for --disable-tls... no
    checking for --enable-intl... yes
    checking for --enable-xlocale... yes
    checking for --enable-config... yes
    checking for --enable-protocols... yes
    checking for --enable-ftp... yes
    checking for --enable-http... yes
    checking for --enable-fileproto... yes
    checking for --enable-sockets... yes
    checking for --enable-ipv6... no
    checking for --enable-ole... yes
    checking for --enable-dataobj... yes
    checking for --enable-ipc... yes
    checking for --enable-baseevtloop... yes
    checking for --enable-epollloop... yes
    checking for --enable-selectloop... yes
    checking for --enable-any... yes
    checking for --enable-apple_ieee... yes
    checking for --enable-arcstream... yes
    checking for --enable-base64... yes
    checking for --enable-backtrace... yes
    checking for --enable-catch_segvs... yes
    checking for --enable-cmdline... yes
    checking for --enable-datetime... yes
    checking for --enable-debugreport... no
    checking for --enable-dialupman... yes
    checking for --enable-dynlib... yes
    checking for --enable-dynamicloader... yes
    checking for --enable-exceptions... yes
    checking for --enable-ffile... yes
    checking for --enable-file... yes
    checking for --enable-filehistory... yes
    checking for --enable-filesystem... yes
    checking for --enable-fontenum... yes
    checking for --enable-fontmap... yes
    checking for --enable-fs_archive... yes
    checking for --enable-fs_inet... yes
    checking for --enable-fs_zip... yes
    checking for --enable-fsvolume... yes
    checking for --enable-fswatcher... yes
    checking for --enable-geometry... yes
    checking for --enable-log... yes
    checking for --enable-longlong... yes
    checking for --enable-mimetype... yes
    checking for --enable-printfposparam... yes
    checking for --enable-snglinst... yes
    checking for --enable-sound... yes
    checking for --enable-stdpaths... yes
    checking for --enable-stopwatch... yes
    checking for --enable-streams... yes
    checking for --enable-sysoptions... yes
    checking for --enable-tarstream... yes
    checking for --enable-textbuf... yes
    checking for --enable-textfile... yes
    checking for --enable-timer... yes
    checking for --enable-variant... yes
    checking for --enable-zipstream... yes
    checking for --enable-url... yes
    checking for --enable-protocol... yes
    checking for --enable-protocol_http... yes
    checking for --enable-protocol_ftp... yes
    checking for --enable-protocol_file... yes
    checking for --enable-threads... yes
    checking for --enable-iniconf... no
    checking for --enable-regkey... yes
    checking for --enable-docview... yes
    checking for --enable-help... yes
    checking for --enable-mshtmlhelp... yes
    checking for --enable-html... yes
    checking for --enable-htmlhelp... yes
    checking for --enable-xrc... yes
    checking for --enable-aui... yes
    checking for --enable-propgrid... yes
    checking for --enable-ribbon... yes
    checking for --enable-stc... yes
    checking for --enable-constraints... yes
    checking for --enable-loggui... yes
    checking for --enable-logwin... yes
    checking for --enable-logdialog... yes
    checking for --enable-mdi... yes
    checking for --enable-mdidoc... yes
    checking for --enable-mediactrl... yes
    checking for --enable-gstreamer8... no
    checking for --enable-richtext... yes
    checking for --enable-postscript... yes
    checking for --enable-printarch... yes
    checking for --enable-svg... yes
    checking for --enable-webkit... yes
    checking for --enable-webview... yes
    checking for --enable-graphics_ctx... yes
    checking for --enable-clipboard... yes
    checking for --enable-dnd... yes
    checking for --disable-controls... no
    checking for --enable-markup... yes
    checking for --enable-accel... yes
    checking for --enable-animatectrl... yes
    checking for --enable-bannerwindow... yes
    checking for --enable-artstd... yes
    checking for --enable-arttango... auto
    checking for --enable-bmpbutton... yes
    checking for --enable-bmpcombobox... yes
    checking for --enable-button... yes
    checking for --enable-calendar... yes
    checking for --enable-caret... yes
    checking for --enable-checkbox... yes
    checking for --enable-checklst... yes
    checking for --enable-choice... yes
    checking for --enable-choicebook... yes
    checking for --enable-collpane... yes
    checking for --enable-colourpicker... yes
    checking for --enable-combobox... yes
    checking for --enable-comboctrl... yes
    checking for --enable-commandlinkbutton... yes
    checking for --enable-dataviewctrl... yes
    checking for --enable-datepick... yes
    checking for --enable-detect_sm... yes
    checking for --enable-dirpicker... yes
    checking for --enable-display... yes
    checking for --enable-editablebox... yes
    checking for --enable-filectrl... yes
    checking for --enable-filepicker... yes
    checking for --enable-fontpicker... yes
    checking for --enable-gauge... yes
    checking for --enable-grid... yes
    checking for --enable-headerctrl... yes
    checking for --enable-hyperlink... yes
    checking for --enable-imaglist... yes
    checking for --enable-infobar... yes
    checking for --enable-listbook... yes
    checking for --enable-listbox... yes
    checking for --enable-listctrl... yes
    checking for --enable-notebook... yes
    checking for --enable-notifmsg... yes
    checking for --enable-odcombobox... yes
    checking for --enable-popupwin... yes
    checking for --enable-prefseditor... yes
    checking for --enable-radiobox... yes
    checking for --enable-radiobtn... yes
    checking for --enable-richmsgdlg... yes
    checking for --enable-richtooltip... yes
    checking for --enable-rearrangectrl... yes
    checking for --enable-sash... yes
    checking for --enable-scrollbar... yes
    checking for --enable-searchctrl... yes
    checking for --enable-slider... yes
    checking for --enable-spinbtn... yes
    checking for --enable-spinctrl... yes
    checking for --enable-splitter... yes
    checking for --enable-statbmp... yes
    checking for --enable-statbox... yes
    checking for --enable-statline... yes
    checking for --enable-stattext... yes
    checking for --enable-statusbar... yes
    checking for --enable-taskbaricon... yes
    checking for --enable-tbarnative... yes
    checking for --enable-textctrl... yes
    checking for --enable-datepick... yes
    checking for --enable-tipwindow... yes
    checking for --enable-togglebtn... yes
    checking for --enable-toolbar... yes
    checking for --enable-toolbook... yes
    checking for --enable-treebook... yes
    checking for --enable-treectrl... yes
    checking for --enable-treelist... yes
    checking for --enable-commondlg... yes
    checking for --enable-aboutdlg... yes
    checking for --enable-choicedlg... yes
    checking for --enable-coldlg... yes
    checking for --enable-filedlg... yes
    checking for --enable-finddlg... yes
    checking for --enable-fontdlg... yes
    checking for --enable-dirdlg... yes
    checking for --enable-msgdlg... yes
    checking for --enable-numberdlg... yes
    checking for --enable-splash... yes
    checking for --enable-textdlg... yes
    checking for --enable-tipdlg... yes
    checking for --enable-progressdlg... yes
    checking for --enable-wizarddlg... yes
    checking for --enable-menus... yes
    checking for --enable-miniframe... yes
    checking for --enable-tooltips... yes
    checking for --enable-splines... yes
    checking for --enable-mousewheel... yes
    checking for --enable-validators... yes
    checking for --enable-busyinfo... yes
    checking for --enable-hotkey... auto
    checking for --enable-joystick... yes
    checking for --enable-metafile... auto
    checking for --enable-dragimage... yes
    checking for --enable-accessibility... no
    checking for --enable-uiactionsim... yes
    checking for --enable-dctransform... yes
    checking for --enable-webviewwebkit... yes
    checking for --enable-palette... yes
    checking for --enable-image... yes
    checking for --enable-gif... yes
    checking for --enable-pcx... yes
    checking for --enable-tga... yes
    checking for --enable-iff... yes
    checking for --enable-pnm... yes
    checking for --enable-xpm... yes
    checking for --enable-ico_cur... yes
    checking for --enable-dccache... yes
    checking for --enable-ps-in-msw... yes
    checking for --enable-ownerdrawn... yes
    checking for --enable-uxtheme... yes
    checking for --enable-wxdib... yes
    checking for --enable-webviewie... yes
    checking for --enable-autoidman... no
    checking for gcc... gcc
    checking whether the C compiler works... yes
    checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
    checking for suffix of executables...
    checking whether we are cross compiling... no
    checking for suffix of object files... o
    checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
    checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
    checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
    checking whether we are using the Intel C compiler... no
    checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
    checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
    checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
    checking whether gcc needs -traditional... no
    checking for g++... g++
    checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
    checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
    checking whether we are using the Intel C++ compiler... no
    checking whether we are using the Sun C++ compiler... no
    checking for ar... ar
    checking for ANSI C header files... yes
    checking for sys/types.h... yes
    checking for sys/stat.h... yes
    checking for stdlib.h... yes
    checking for string.h... yes
    checking for memory.h... yes
    checking for strings.h... yes
    checking for inttypes.h... yes
    checking for stdint.h... yes
    checking for unistd.h... yes
    checking for langinfo.h... yes
    checking for wchar.h... yes
    checking for sys/select.h... yes
    checking for cxxabi.h... yes
    checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
    checking for inline... inline
    checking size of short... 2
    checking size of void *... 8
    checking size of int... 4
    checking size of long... 8
    checking size of size_t... 8
    checking size of long long... 8
    checking size of wchar_t... 4
    checking for va_copy... yes
    checking whether the compiler supports variadic macros... yes
    checking for _FILE_OFFSET_BITS value needed for large files... 64
    checking if large file support is available... yes
    checking for _LARGEFILE_SOURCE value needed for large files... no
    checking whether byte ordering is bigendian... no
    checking for iostream... yes
    checking if C++ compiler supports the explicit keyword... yes
    checking for std::wstring in <string>... yes
    checking for std::istream... yes
    checking for std::ostream... yes
    checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
    checking type_traits usability... yes
    checking type_traits presence... yes
    checking for type_traits... yes
    checking for __sync_fetch_and_add and __sync_sub_and_fetch builtins... yes
    checking for libraries directories... /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/lib
    checking for cos... no
    checking for floor... no
    checking if floating point functions link without -lm... no
    checking for sin... yes
    checking for ceil... yes
    checking if floating point functions link with -lm... yes
    checking for strtoull... yes
    configure: WARNING: Defaulting to the builtin regex library for Unicode build.
    checking for zlib.h >= 1.1.4... yes
    checking for zlib.h... (cached) yes
    checking for deflate in -lz... yes
    checking for png.h > 0.90... yes
    checking for png.h... (cached) yes
    checking for png_sig_cmp in -lpng... yes
    checking for jpeglib.h... no
    configure: WARNING: system jpeg library not found, will use built-in instead
    checking for tiffio.h... no
    configure: WARNING: system tiff library not found, will use built-in instead
    checking for lzma_code in -llzma... no
    checking for jbg_dec_init in -ljbig... no
    checking for expat.h... yes
    checking if expat.h is valid C++ header... yes
    checking for XML_ParserCreate in -lexpat... yes
    checking for GTK+ version...
    checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
    checking for GTK+ - version >= 3.0.0... yes (version 3.22.11)
    checking for X11/Xlib.h... yes
    checking for X11/XKBlib.h... yes
    checking for Xxf86vm... yes
    checking for X11/extensions/xf86vmode.h... yes
    checking for SM... yes
    checking for OpenGL headers... not found
    checking for GL/gl.h... no
    configure: error: OpenGL libraries not available
    Error running configure
    ERROR: failed building wxWidgets
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "build.py", line 1270, in cmd_build_wx
        wxbuild.main(wxDir(), build_options)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-AgBlvu/wxPython/buildtools/build_wxwidgets.py", line 376, in main
        "Error running configure")
      File "/tmp/pip-build-AgBlvu/wxPython/buildtools/build_wxwidgets.py", line 85, in exitIfError
        raise builder.BuildError(msg)
    BuildError
    Finished command: build_wx (4.379s)
    Finished command: build (4.379s)
    Command '"/usr/bin/python" -u build.py build' failed with exit code 1.

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-AgBlvu/wxPython/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-q84GOx-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-AgBlvu/wxPython/
```

I tried using virtual environment but still can't get it to work. Any idea on how to fix this?
PS: Excuse the redundancy in the beginning. But it wouldn't have let me post if I hadn't done that.

Comment: `configure: error: OpenGL libraries not available` doesn't look promising

Comment: Yeah, you most likely need to install OpenGL

Comment: See also the comments at https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix/issues/472

Comment: Thanks a lot guys.